# is Visual Studio Pro 2013 license valid for Visual Studio Pro 2017?

Tags: visual-studio

I have licensed Visual Studio Professional 2013 installed on my computer. Is the same license valid for Visual Studio Pro 2017? If yes, how can I upgrade to Visual Studio Pro 2017.

Answer (score 0):

It is not valid, but you can install 2017 Community Edition for free and you likely won't miss much.